# Android image scaling in the Gallery

Tags: android, gallery, scale

I have two images in a Gallery view. First I add a 80x80 image, and then a bigger one (400x400). I want both images to be displayed as 80x80 to match the size of the first image.

If I hardcode the size

```
image.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(80, 80));
image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
```

all goes OK. But if I try to evade the hardcoding in case that the first image will be changed

```
image.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
```

the big image is displayed as 400x80, and is not scaled: only the central slice of it is visible.

How can I make all the images in the Gallery to be scaled to match the size of the first added image without specifying that size directly?

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
image.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
```